# Android Login Authentication with Session

Tags: php, android, authentication, session-cookies

I know that a login authentication has been covered before.  However, I am having some trouble implementing it.  So a far I have a basic form in the android app that sends the login credentials to my server.  After the credentials have been verified, how do I create a token session in the php api?

Do I simply use:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
$_SESSION['auth'] = "true";
```

If so how do I pass this session into the android application?

Login Authentification in Android App:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://www.somewebsite.com/login.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
// Get the response
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
```